# get string values from a text file (town name & postal code) and insert into URL

Tags: language-agnostic, notepad++

I'm trying to get some values from a text file (town names & postal code) and paste it to an url to interogate an external website:

In the text file the values are:

```
"PARIS 75010"
"LILLE 59000"
...
```

I want to insert those values into the following url:
http://fr.mappy.com/#d=Town,+postalcode,+departement,+France&p=map

Since I have a lot of values to treat i need a simple way to do this.

Any ideas :)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The answers will look vastly different between PHP and C++. Which do you want?

Comment: I have notepad++ i don't care on the language in only need to treat some text files

Answer (score 0):

Your tags say PHP and C++, but a simple way to do this might be to use a shell script.  Just read the lines from the file and then invoke the program `curl` to do the HTTP GET.  For example:

```
while read town code; do
    curl "http://fr.mappy.com/#d=$town,+$code..."
done
```

Comment: I have notepad++ and need to read from several external files

Comment: sorry if my questions are dumb but I have poor programming knowledge and need to treat more than 5000 data

Comment: I think the answer is that you need to find someone with some programming knowledge and get them to bang out the solution for you.  This site is more about answering specific questions and less about providing entire programs.  The code I gave you above is simple but not too far away from something that would work.  I think you might just need to run it a few times, once for each of your files, or else you can use a program such as "cat" to concatenate all your input files into one file before use.

Comment: ok thanks i'm using my linux now i will keep you informed on my progress. Thanks for your help